# debconf is broken or not fully installed

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

I tried to install python 2.7.3 from python 2.7.13 and then I got a problem with debconf 
everytime I try to upgrade or install something, this always show up :

```
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Help me please guys

```
apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  aapt clang curl graphviz gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad ipython king-phisher
  libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libfbclient2 libgeos-c1v5 libgspell-1-1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libkpathsea6 libnma-common libnma0
  libosinfo-1.0-0 libpoppler-glib8 libptexenc1 libradare2-dev libsynctex1
  libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 linux-image-amd64 mesa-utils mitmproxy mpg123
  nautilus nautilus-data network-manager-gnome poppler-utils postgresql
  python-html5lib python-matplotlib python-pycurl python-twisted
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-wheel python-yara
  python3-louis radare2 reportbug rsyslog sparta speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins texlive-base texlive-binaries
  texlive-latex-base tightvncserver vim vim-common vim-gtk vim-gui-common
  vim-runtime vim-tiny xpdf xtightvncviewer zeitgeist-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up debconf (1.5.60) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up debconf (1.5.60) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  espeak-data firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc libchromaprint0
  libespeak1 libgeos-3.5.0 libglew1.13 liblouis10 libmimic0
  libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libosinfo-db
  libperl5.22 libpoppler61 libradare2-0.9.9 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libwildmidi1
  libx265-79
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clang-3.8 espeak-ng-data firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc libann0
  libclang-common-3.8-dev libclang1-3.8 libespeak-ng1 libfastjson4
  libfltk-images1.3 libfltk1.3 libgeos-3.5.1 libglew2.0 libgnome-autoar-0-0
  libgnome-autoar-common libgspell-1-common libidn2-0 libjansson4 libjsoncpp1
  liblilv-0-0 libllvm3.8 liblognorm5 liblouis12 libobjc-6-dev libout123-0
  libpcaudio0 libpoppler64 libprotobuf-lite10 libradare2-1.1 libserd-0-0
  libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libtommath1 libwildmidi2 libxapian30 libyara3
  linux-image-4.9.0-kali1-amd64 llvm-3.8 llvm-3.8-dev llvm-3.8-runtime
  osinfo-db postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6
  python-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size python-brotlipy python-constantly
  python-cssutils python-functools32 python-incremental python-ipython
  python-ipython-genutils python-jsbeautifier python-keyring
  python-keyrings.alt python-pathlib2 python-pickleshare python-pluginbase
  python-prompt-toolkit python-secretstorage python-subprocess32
  python-traitlets python-typing python-wcwidth python-webencodings
  python3-debianbts python3-httplib2 python3-pysimplesoap python3-reportbug
  speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng tigervnc-common tigervnc-standalone-server
  tigervnc-viewer xsltproc xxd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aapt clang curl graphviz gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad ipython king-phisher
  libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libfbclient2 libgeos-c1v5 libgspell-1-1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libkpathsea6 libnma-common libnma0
  libosinfo-1.0-0 libpoppler-glib8 libptexenc1 libradare2-dev libsynctex1
  libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 linux-image-amd64 mesa-utils mitmproxy mpg123
  nautilus nautilus-data network-manager-gnome poppler-utils postgresql
  python-html5lib python-matplotlib python-pycurl python-twisted
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-wheel python-yara
  python3-louis radare2 reportbug rsyslog sparta speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins texlive-base texlive-binaries
  texlive-latex-base tightvncserver vim vim-common vim-gtk vim-gui-common
  vim-runtime vim-tiny xpdf xtightvncviewer zeitgeist-core
60 upgraded, 75 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 166 MB of archives.
After this operation, 546 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxapian30 amd64 1.4.2-1 [1,064 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libfastjson4 amd64 0.99.4-1 [22.7 kB]
Get:3 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liblognorm5 amd64 2.0.1-1.1 [57.3 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 rsyslog amd64 8.24.0-1 [553 kB]
Get:5 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-gtk amd64 2:8.0.0197-1 [1,263 kB]
Get:6 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.0.0197-1 [1,033 kB]
Get:7 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.0.0197-1 [446 kB]
Get:8 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.0.0197-1 [5,408 kB]
Get:9 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.0.0197-1 [158 kB]
Get:10 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vim-gui-common all 2:8.0.0197-1 [159 kB]
Get:11 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.0.0197-1 [131 kB]
Get:12 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-httplib2 all 0.9.2+dfsg-1 [33.6 kB]
Get:13 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-pysimplesoap all 1.16-2 [38.4 kB]
Get:14 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-debianbts all 2.6.1 [11.3 kB]
Get:15 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-reportbug all 7.1.2 [126 kB]
Get:16 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 reportbug all 7.1.2 [126 kB]
Get:17 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libllvm3.8 amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [10.4 MB]
Get:18 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libclang1-3.8 amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [4,187 kB]
Get:19 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libobjc-6-dev amd64 6.3.0-5 [198 kB]
Get:20 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libclang-common-3.8-dev amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [2,197 kB]
Get:21 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 clang-3.8 amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [22.8 MB]
Get:22 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 clang amd64 1:3.8-34+b1 [5,894 B]
Get:23 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libidn2-0 amd64 0.16-1 [60.6 kB]
Get:24 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libcurl3 amd64 7.52.1-1 [290 kB]
Get:25 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 curl amd64 7.52.1-1 [227 kB]
Get:26 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 espeak-ng-data amd64 1.49.0+dfsg-7 [2,463 kB]
Get:27 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 firebird3.0-common-doc all 3.0.1.32609.ds4-13 [36.2 kB]
Get:28 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 firebird3.0-common all 3.0.1.32609.ds4-13 [13.7 kB]
Get:29 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libann0 amd64 1.1.2+doc-6 [24.9 kB]
Get:30 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 graphviz amd64 2.38.0-16 [798 kB]
Get:31 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-pathlib2 all 2.2.0+really2.1.0-1 [16.5 kB]
Get:32 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-pickleshare all 0.7.4-1 [6,736 B]
Get:33 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-wcwidth all 0.1.7+dfsg1-1 [14.6 kB]
Get:34 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-prompt-toolkit all 1.0.9-1 [174 kB]
Get:35 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-ipython-genutils all 0.1.0-2 [20.7 kB]
Get:36 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-traitlets all 4.3.1-1 [60.6 kB]
Get:37 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size all 1.0.0-3 [4,656 B]
Get:38 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ipython all 5.1.0-3 [5,496 B]
Get:39 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-ipython all 5.1.0-3 [375 kB]
Get:40 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-functools32 all 3.2.3.2-3 [11.0 kB]
Get:41 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-subprocess32 amd64 3.2.7-2 [28.9 kB]
Get:42 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-matplotlib amd64 2.0.0-3 [1,596 kB]
Get:43 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-pluginbase all 0.4-0kali1 [7,708 B]
Get:44 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 postgresql-client-9.6 amd64 9.6.1-2 [1,208 kB]
Get:45 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 postgresql-9.6 amd64 9.6.1-2 [4,016 kB]
Get:46 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 postgresql all 9.6+178 [55.1 kB]
Get:47 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 king-phisher all 1.4.0-0kali1 [224 kB]
Get:48 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.52.1-1 [288 kB]
Get:49 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpcaudio0 amd64 1.0-1 [6,798 B]
Get:50 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libespeak-ng1 amd64 1.49.0+dfsg-7 [167 kB]
Get:51 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libtommath1 amd64 1.0-4 [56.0 kB]
Get:52 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libfbclient2 amd64 3.0.1.32609.ds4-13 [504 kB]
Get:53 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libfltk1.3 amd64 1.3.3-8+b1 [523 kB]
Get:54 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libfltk-images1.3 amd64 1.3.3-8+b1 [52.6 kB]
Get:55 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgeos-3.5.1 amd64 3.5.1-3 [611 kB]
Get:56 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgeos-c1v5 amd64 3.5.1-3 [187 kB]
Get:57 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libglew2.0 amd64 2.0.0-3 [143 kB]
Get:58 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgnome-autoar-common all 0.1.1-4 [3,152 B]
Get:59 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgnome-autoar-0-0 amd64 0.1.1-4+b1 [24.2 kB]
Get:60 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgspell-1-common all 1.2.2-1 [24.9 kB]
Get:61 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgspell-1-1 amd64 1.2.2-1 [42.5 kB]
Get:62 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libjansson4 amd64 2.9-1 [28.1 kB]
Get:63 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libkpathsea6 amd64 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 [159 kB]
Get:64 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 texlive-binaries amd64 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 [7,389 kB]
Get:65 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libptexenc1 amd64 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 [57.8 kB]
Get:66 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsynctex1 amd64 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 [64.7 kB]
Get:67 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libtexlua52 amd64 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 [111 kB]
Get:68 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libtexluajit2 amd64 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 [249 kB]
Get:69 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpoppler64 amd64 0.48.0-2 [1,285 kB]
Get:70 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libserd-0-0 amd64 0.26.0~dfsg0-1 [45.3 kB]
Get:71 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsord-0-0 amd64 0.16.0~dfsg0-1 [22.7 kB]
Get:72 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libsratom-0-0 amd64 0.6.0~dfsg0-1 [16.6 kB]
Get:73 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liblilv-0-0 amd64 0.24.2~dfsg0-1 [42.7 kB]
Get:74 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 network-manager-gnome amd64 1.4.2-1 [970 kB]
Get:75 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libnma0 amd64 1.4.2-1 [122 kB]
Get:76 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libnma-common all 1.4.2-1 [60.3 kB]
Get:77 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libout123-0 amd64 1.23.8-1 [37.7 kB]
Get:78 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpoppler-glib8 amd64 0.48.0-2 [122 kB]
Get:79 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libprotobuf-lite10 amd64 3.0.0-9 [125 kB]
Get:80 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libwildmidi2 amd64 0.4.0-2 [60.9 kB]
Get:81 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libyara3 amd64 3.5.0+dfsg-8 [102 kB]
Get:82 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-image-4.9.0-kali1-amd64 amd64 4.9.6-3kali2 [37.9 MB]
Get:83 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-image-amd64 amd64 4.9+78+kali1 [7,246 B]
Get:84 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-3.8-runtime amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [87.2 kB]
Get:85 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-3.8 amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [1,547 kB]
Get:86 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libjsoncpp1 amd64 1.7.4-3 [75.6 kB]
Get:87 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 llvm-3.8-dev amd64 1:3.8.1-17 [16.1 MB]
Get:88 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 mesa-utils amd64 8.3.0-3 [32.7 kB]
Get:89 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-brotlipy amd64 0.6-0kali1 [281 kB]
Get:90 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-cssutils all 1.0-4.1 [204 kB]
Get:91 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-jsbeautifier all 1.6.4-6 [45.5 kB]
Get:92 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-typing all 3.5.2.2-1 [19.1 kB]
Get:93 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 mitmproxy all 0.18.2-6kali1 [1,079 kB]
Get:94 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 mpg123 amd64 1.23.8-1 [167 kB]
Get:95 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 nautilus amd64 3.22.2-1 [746 kB]
Get:96 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 nautilus-data all 3.22.2-1 [1,701 kB]
Get:97 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 osinfo-db all 0.20160728+git20161020-1 [61.2 kB]
Get:98 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 poppler-utils amd64 0.48.0-2 [151 kB]
Get:99 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 postgresql-contrib-9.6 amd64 9.6.1-2 [494 kB]
Get:100 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-constantly all 15.1.0-1 [7,902 B]
Get:101 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-webencodings all 0.5-2 [10.3 kB]
Get:102 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-html5lib all 0.999999999-1 [88.0 kB]
Get:103 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-incremental all 16.10.1-3 [14.4 kB]
Get:104 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-secretstorage all 2.3.1-2 [13.8 kB]
Get:105 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-keyring all 10.1-1 [40.7 kB]
Get:106 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-keyrings.alt all 1.3-1 [16.4 kB]
Get:107 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-pycurl amd64 7.43.0-2 [61.6 kB]
Get:108 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-twisted-core all 16.6.0-2 [1,979 kB]
Get:109 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-twisted-web all 16.6.0-2 [79.8 kB]
Get:110 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-wheel all 0.29.0-2 [51.7 kB]
Get:111 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-yara amd64 3.5.0+dfsg-4 [13.8 kB]
Get:112 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xsltproc amd64 1.1.29-2 [120 kB]
Get:113 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 sparta all 1.0.1+git20150729-0kali2 [257 kB]
Get:114 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 speech-dispatcher amd64 0.8.6-1 [364 kB]
Get:115 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins amd64 0.8.6-1 [30.8 kB]
Get:116 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng amd64 0.8.6-1 [45.3 kB]
Get:117 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 texlive-latex-base all 2016.20161130-1 [861 kB]
Get:118 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 texlive-base all 2016.20161130-1 [15.8 MB]
Get:119 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tigervnc-common amd64 1.7.0+dfsg-2 [65.9 kB]
Get:120 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tigervnc-standalone-server amd64 1.7.0+dfsg-2 [995 kB]
Get:121 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tigervnc-viewer amd64 1.7.0+dfsg-2 [167 kB]
Get:122 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tightvncserver amd64 1.3.9+t-1 [13.3 kB]
Get:123 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xpdf amd64 3.04-4 [159 kB]
Get:124 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xtightvncviewer amd64 1.3.9+t-1 [13.2 kB]
Get:125 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 zeitgeist-core amd64 0.9.16-0.2 [137 kB]
Get:126 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 aapt amd64 1:7.0.0+r1-2 [391 kB]
Get:127 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad amd64 1.10.2-1 [2,971 kB]
Get:128 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 amd64 1.10.2-1 [1,874 kB]
Get:129 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liblouis12 amd64 3.0.0-3 [86.8 kB]
Get:130 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libosinfo-1.0-0 amd64 1.0.0-2 [150 kB]
Get:131 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libradare2-1.1 amd64 1.1.0+dfsg-1 [2,052 kB]
Get:132 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libradare2-dev amd64 1.1.0+dfsg-1 [146 kB]
Get:133 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-twisted all 16.6.0-2 [12.2 kB]
Get:134 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-louis all 3.0.0-3 [23.5 kB]
Get:135 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 radare2 amd64 1.1.0+dfsg-1 [151 kB]
Fetched 166 MB in 6min 28s (427 kB/s)                                          
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up debconf (1.5.60) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13

sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up debconf (1.5.60) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You'll have to use copy and paste and give us the exact command you are using for your install, as well as the exact error message.  The message that you are showing is had to do with trying to configure something that isn't installed and has to be installed first.

Comment: when I enter apt-get upgrade for example it show up, I can't install anything

Comment: also when I enter this command: " dpkg --configure -a ", this shows up              dpkg: error processing package man-db (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
 man-db

Comment: Those words `I can't install anything` don't appear on my computer.   If I type those words into Google to see how others have resolved the issue, I don't get any hits that are legible.  If you could copy the exact command and the exact error message it would be very easy to find a resolution.  Any error you get won't be the first.  The error messages are exact and have exact resolutions.

Comment: I edited the command in the question

Comment: The exact command should have been `sudo apt upgrade`.  I'm sure you typed in **sudo** otherwise it would not have gone as far.  Now try this: edit your question and add this command and the output of it, using copy and paste, so that we can see the exact wording.  `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Also run this:  `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Debconf is not broken - the title is misleading. Looks more like you (unwisely) modified the original version of Python2. Don't do that - essential system services (like apt) rely upon that specific version of python2. You can install multiple versions of python2 on your system...but not by using the package manager.

Comment: @L.D.James still the same thing

Comment: Will you use your arrow keys and browse so that you can see the exact command you typed in when you modified `python` which was already installed by default.  Seeing exactly what you typed in will help us to be able to figure out how to fix the problem it has caused.  Also run `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: it's not there anymore I did reboot the computer and tried many things, I remember when I entered python it showed python 2.7.13 and I did an installation for python 2.7.3

Comment: I remember I followed the exact same steps of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4AgCELJHVM but it's not the same versions than him, I thought it will work just fine, I had version 2.7.13 and I installed 2.7.3

Comment: One of the problems is that the video is for `Kali` and not `Ubuntu`.  As far s reviewing the history of your typed commands, they will survive a reboot.  You could most likely hit the uparrow enough times to see the commands you've typed in for a week.  Looking at the video, you may have used a variation of `sudo make install`.  You can try to remove the problem install by, first going to the folder where you compiled the package and run `sudo make uninstall`.  If you show output, you don't have to show the full output, just the last 10 or so lines should show a sufficient result.

Comment: Also run `sudo apt install --reinstall python`

Comment: Could not help but notice that in all of the command examples in this question,  there is an IOError ...unable to find /usr/lib/python2.7/MAKEfile. Looked in that path on my machine and can find no MAKEfile in that path.

Answer (score 1):

**Debconf isn't broken**.  You have a broken install of a package you attempted to install that doesn't have the libraries properly installed.  Debconf is informing you of this.  This is indicated in the message, showing that you have **1 not fully installed or removed**.  It can't remove the packages that you have manually installed because they were not installed using the Debconf (**apt install**) system which will include a configuration of where all the files that were added during the install process, where they are, and which files are depended on the installation.

You can still install and remove applications from the repository using either the GUI **software center** or the command-line **apt install**.

To remove the errors and notices of your output, you would have to manually remove the failed package that you manually attempted to install.

### How to remove manually installed applications

This can be done by studying the files in the package you downloaded and looking for a method provided by the distributor of how to uninstall the package.  This will usually be found in a **Readme.txt** or **Install.txt** file with instructions of how to remove or how to install.

In many circumstances the the library's author will provide a method for removing the file such as `sudo make uninstall`.  The **make** command has a dry run option that doesn't make any changes to the system, but shows what it will do.  You can run:

```
$ make -n install
```

Then manually remove the problem files.  You will have to be careful with the files you remove.  If the files are used with a different package, the other package may become broken.  In that case, if you develop a problem with a different package you can bring the other package back to it's proper state with:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall [package name]
```

In this case running this will properly install python from the repository:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall python
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite this is a bit overkill, a quick fix for this problem is to use conda:

[Download and install](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html#install-linux-silent)

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
# Follow the prompts on the installer screens
# Close and then re-open your terminal window
```

A base environment should be activated, check which python version is installed, and in case you need a different version just install it with conda and activate it:

```
# install
conda create --name base_python2 python=2
# or
conda create --name base_python3 python=3

# activate env
conda activate base_python2
# or
conda activate base_python3
```

Note: if you want to set a default python version different from the one it was stablished to be the `base` env, you can add the activation line into your `.bashrc`.